# Total time complexity when each step takes O(log n) operations

Tags: time-complexity, logarithm

Consider a tree where the cost of an insertion is in `O(log n)`. Say you start from an empty tree and add N elements iteratively. We want to know the total time complexity. I did this:

```
nb of operations in iteration i = log i
nb of operations in all iterations from 1 to N = log 1 + log 2 + ... + log N = log( N! ) 
total complexity =  O(N!) ~ O(N log N)
```

(cf the Stirling approximation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation )

Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe better fit in math.stackexchange. Intuitively though, NlogN sounds right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's nearly correct.

A small correction: in the `i`th step, the number of operations is *not* `log i`, as most of the time that's an irrational number, it's `O(log i)`. So for a mathematically tight proof you have to work a bit harder, but in short, what you wrote is the essence of the proof.